# how to fetch data from multiple table?

Tags: mysql, sql

what i want is all the record from tbmedAssign where zoneid or zone name given as parameter.
how to wrote query for this?
please help.

table name 
tablzone

```
zone_id(PK)   ZoneName
-----------   --------
1             east
2             west
3             north
4             south

tbluser

usrId(PK) userzoneId(FK to tblzone)   username
--------  -------------------------   ------------
1         1                           manish
2         3                           rahul
3         2                           ankit
4         4                           amir
5         2                           rashmi
6         1                           akash
tbldoctor

docId(PK)    usrId(Fk to tbluser)      docname
--------     --------------------      ------------
1             2                        hemant
2             2                        chintu
3             3                        rahim
4             1                        salman
5             3                        kishor
6             3                        saurabh
7             2                        banti

tblmedAssign 

transId(Pk)  doctorId(FK to tbldoctor)    medId(FK)    dateInsert
----------   -------------------------    ------   -----------
1            2                            2        20/12/2012
2            3                            3        21/12/2012
3            2                            3        23/12/2012
4            4                            1        24/12/2012
```

tblmedia

```
medid(PK)   medianame 
---------   ---------
1           casfung 
2           inem 
3           media1
4           tplan
5           casfung test
```

i want all the record from tblmedAssign where doctor belongs to particular user in tbluser and in the tbluser user is belongs to particular zone and zone id is provided as parameter? for example zoneid= 1;

i want to select medianame too in the record

Comment: Your explanation needs a bit clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to join the four tables with their linking columns. Try this,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.*,
        c.*,        
        d.*,
        e.*
FROM    tblmedAssign a
        INNER JOIN tblDoctor b
            ON a.doctorID = b.docID
        INNER JOIN tblUser c
            ON b.usrID = c.usrID
        INNER JOIN tblZone d
            ON c.userzoneID = d.zone_ID
        INNER JOIN tblmedAssign e
            ON e.medid = a.medid
WHERE   d.zone_id = @zone_id OR    -- supply value here
        d.zoneName = @zoneName
```

Comment: thanx john this worked. can i ask for few more complex query?

Comment: @ManishMalviya sure. if i could :D

Comment: john i have updated 1 more table tblmedia i want to select medianame of the particular record.

Comment: and where is `tblmedia` connected?

Comment: @ManishMalviya see the updated answer :D hope it worked.

Answer (score 0):

By `JOIN`ing the three tables, something like:

```
SELECT -- what you want to select
FROM tblmedAssign ta
LEFT JOIN tbldoctor td ON ta.doctorId = td.docId
LEFT JOIN tbluser tu ON td.usrId = tu.usrId
LEFT JOIN tablzone tz ON tu.userzoneId = tz.zone_Id
WHERE tz.zone_Id = @zoneIdParam
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tblmedAssign 
inner join tbldoctor on tbldoctor.docId = tblmedAssign.doctorId
inner join tbluser on tbluser.usrId = tbldoctor.usrId
inner join tablzone on tablzone.zone_id = tbluser.userzoneId
where tablzone.ZoneName = 'east' 
or tablzone.zone_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should serve your purpose

```
select * 
from
tblmedAssign, tbldoctor, tbluser, tablzone 
where
tblmedAssign.doctorId = tbldoctor.docId and 
tbldoctor.usrId = tbluser.usrId and 
tbluser.userzoneId =  tablzone.zone_id and 
(tablzone.zone_id = x or tablzone.ZoneName = 'y')
```